# Xamarin Form: Select ViewCell data through Button

Tags: uitableview, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` in which I have button. And I want to select the `ViewCell`'s data when I click on the button.

Here is my XAML code

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--<Image Source="{Binding image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}"  HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />-->
                <StackLayout Padding="6" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding strItemName}" FontSize="13"
                        />
                    <Label Text="{Binding numSalePrice, StringFormat='Rs. {0:N}'}" FontSize="11"
                       TextColor="#da3043" />
                </StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Add To Cart" WidthRequest="100" 
                        HeightRequest="31"
                        BackgroundColor="#10c3f2"
                        FontSize="10"
                   TextColor="White"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I don't want to work with `ViewCellTap`, I need to get the `ViewCell`'s data from the button inside the `ListView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can bind the data to CommandParameter

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding .}" ...
```

then in your event handler

```
protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs a) 
{
  // assuming your data is a type MyClass
  var item = (MyClass)((Button)sender).CommandParameter;

  // now you can ref item.strItemName, item.numSalePrice, etc
}
```